# What is the overall impact of ignoring data at FIFO input in an FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, fifo, hdl

I understand the operation of a FIFO, but I think I am missing something about it's utility.

When implementing a FIFO in an FPGA, let's say to cross clock domains, it seems that you would frequently run into the situation where the FIFO is full, but there is still data that should be clocking in every cycle. This might happen if the writing mechanism is clocking data in faster than the reading mechanism is reading data out. Obviously, once the FIFO is full it will start ignoring data until it has room to continue storing data.

My question is, isn't this a big deal? We are basically just losing data? Sure the FIFO is doing it's job, but the overall system is just throwing away data

I have drawn two possible conclusions

1) In this scenario (where the input data rate is greater than the output data rate), if we really care about not losing any data, maybe a FIFO isn't the best way to cross these domains (especially if the writing mechanism is much faster clock than the reading domain). If this is true, is there conventionally a better way to cross clock domains than with a FIFO? Maybe the answer is that you need to use another element, such as a decimator, before the FIFO?

2) We put a constraint on the system that says "you can only write for X amount of data (or cycles, or time etc.)" before the FIFO needs time to clear it's data. This seems unsatisfactory to me that we must turn off the data stream for a little while and wait for the FIFO to clear some room until we continue writing. But then again, I'm new to digital systems and maybe this is just the harsh reality that I am not used to :)

It seems then that the best use for a FIFO when crossing clock domains is simply one where the data rate into the FIFO and the data rate out of the FIFO are the same, because then it can keep up with itself.

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. A specific electronics design problem may be [on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Two rules of FIFOs: never write to a full FIFO, never read from an empty FIFO.  Never break the rules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing two problems into one.

There's clock domain crossing, and input data buffering. It just happens that FIFO combines implementations for these two tasks in one entity.

If the receiver can't keep up with transmitter, and there's no flow control, then the data will be lost, and it doesn't matter if data was crossing the clock domains or not. You can't solve the data loss problem without adding some kind of handshake or flow control lines.

Without flow control you must ensure that the input buffer size is enough for handling load peaks in your specific case.

As for impacts - it's either nonexistant if your design is ok with data loss, or you'll have a nonfunctional device if the data loss is not tolerated by the design.

Comment: By flow control, you must mean control other than "full"/"empty" and "almost full"/"almost empty" control signals? 

For example, control signals that would tell the transmitter to stop transmitting data until the receiver was ready to accept more data?

Comment: @jakedaly I mean exactly that. See the various interfaces. `CTS/RTS` in UART, `waitrequest` in Avalon-MM or `ready` in Avalon-ST. That's the bare minimum required to guarantee that data won't be lost. "Almost full/empty" is something specific, and not needed in most cases.

Comment: @jakedaly Its important to note that in the case of producer created output faster than a consumer can input it, you generally have two options: lose any data the consumer cannot take in, or have the consumer apply back pressure to the producer to stall production of data. Which is best for your system depends on what the data is, but if you need all data, flow control is the mechanism by which back pressure is implemented. Sometimes, the producer only creates data faster for a short time, that is where buffering techniques like FIFOs become important.

Answer (score 0):

FIFOs have also the functionality of different input and output widths. That means for example you have an 100 Mhz 32 Bit Input and an 50Mhz 64bit output. The data rate into and out of the fifo ist half but the data widht is double.